# Run Time Error with a Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So, I've tried to implement a doubly linked list in C++.
It compiles just fine, but the moment it runs, it crashes and exits. 
It just says "Process returned -1073741819"

(I'm using Code::Blocks and the GNU GCC Compiler btw)

I have a feeling that the problem lies in the constructor, but I'm not exactly sure. I've tried experimenting around with it, but to no avail.

Any ideas what might be spawning the run time error? Any pointers (no pun intended) to what might trigger the issue will be greatly appreciated!

DNode.h

```
#ifndef DNODE_H_INCLUDED
#define DNODE_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ostream>

class DNode{

private:
    int elem;
    DNode* next;
    DNode* prev;
    friend class DList;
public:
    DNode(int value=0){
        elem= value;
        next= NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }
};


#endif // DNODE_H_INCLUDED
```

DList.h

```
#ifndef DLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define DLIST_H_INCLUDED
#include "DNode.h"

using namespace std;

class DList{

private:
    DNode* head;
    DNode* tail;

public:
    DList(){
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    ~DList();
    void display();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    const int& getFront() const;
    const int& getRear() const;
    void addFront(const int& e);
    void addRear(const int& e);
    void removeFront();
    void removeRear();
    void addMiddleBefore(const int&e, const int& pos);
    void addMiddleAfter(const int&e, const int& pos);
    bool isIn(const int& e);
    void removeNode(const int& e);

};




#endif // DLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

DList.cpp

```
#include "DList.h"
#include "DNode.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DList::display(){
DNode* cur = head;
while((cur->next) != tail){
    cout<<cur->elem<<"->";
    cur = cur -> next;
}
cout<<endl;
}


bool DList::isEmpty()const {
DNode* cur = head;
if((cur->next) = tail){
    cout<<"Yep, the list is empty!"<<endl;
    return true;
}
else{
    cout<<"Nope,not empty"<<endl;
    return false;
}
}

const int& DList::getFront() const{
cout<<"The first element is " <<endl;
return head->elem;
}

const int& DList::getRear() const{
cout<<"The last element is "<<endl;
return tail->elem;
}

void DList::addFront(const int& e){
DNode* temp = new DNode(e);
DNode* cur = head;

temp->next = cur->next;
temp->prev = cur;
cur->next->prev = temp;
cur->next = temp;
cout<<"Added element to the front"<<endl;
}


void DList::addRear(const int& e){
DNode* temp = new DNode(e);
DNode* cur = tail;

temp->next = cur;
temp->prev = cur->prev;
cur->prev->next = temp;
cur->prev = temp;
cout<<"Added element to the rear"<<endl;
}

void DList::addMiddleBefore(const int&e, const int& pos){
DNode*temp = new DNode(e);
DNode *cur = head;

while((cur->elem) != pos ){
    cur = cur -> next;
}
temp->next = cur;
temp->prev = cur->prev;
cur->prev->next = temp;
cur->prev = temp;
cout<<"Added node"<<endl;
}

void DList::addMiddleAfter(const int&e, const int& pos){
DNode* temp = new DNode(e);
DNode* cur = head;

while((cur->elem) != pos){
    cur = cur -> next;
}

temp ->next = cur->next;
temp->prev = cur;
cur->next->prev = temp;
cur->next = temp;
cout<<"Added node"<<endl;

}

void DList::removeFront(){
DNode* temp = head;
temp->next->prev = head;
head = head -> next;
delete temp;
cout<<"Deleted Front"<<endl;
}


void DList::removeRear(){
DNode* temp = tail;
temp->prev->next = tail;
tail = tail -> prev;
delete temp;
cout<<"Deleted Rear"<<endl;
}

void DList::removeNode(const int & e){
DNode* cur = head;
while((cur->elem) != e){
    cur = cur -> next;
}
cur->prev->next = cur->next;
cur->next->prev = cur->prev;
delete cur;
cout<<"Deleted node"<<endl;
}

bool DList::isIn(const int &e){
DNode* cur = head;
while((cur->next) != tail){
    if (cur->elem == e){
        cout<<"Found"<<endl;
        return true;
    }
cur = cur->next;
}
cout<<"Not found"<<endl;
return false;
}

DList::~DList(){
while((!isEmpty())) removeFront();
}
```

DNode.cpp

```
#include "DNode.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "DList.h"
#include "DNode.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DList newList;
int main()
{
    newList.addFront(50);
    newList.addRear(4);
    newList.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Compiler likely raising a warning over: `if((cur->next) = tail){` Don't ignore warnings. They are the compiler telling you you probably have a simple logic error.

Comment: When you create a new `DList`, `head` starts as `NULL`.  Then when you call `addFront`, you dereference that null pointer here: `DNode* cur = head;` `temp->next = cur->next;`.

Comment: That should just about be enough for an answer right there, @0x5453 .

Comment: Some helpful reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @0x5453 Yikes, I see. Just fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @user4581301 Oh right...my bad, I just addressed it!

Comment: @user4581301 And, thanks for the resource! It looks really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Making my comment an answer.

I see at least one problem: When you create a new `DList`, `head` starts as `NULL`.  Then when you call `addFront`, you dereference that null pointer here:

```
DNode* cur = head; 

temp->next = cur->next;
```

Note that if you run your code through a debugger, it should in most cases tell you the exact line where the crash occurred, and will let you inspect the values of all variables at the time of the crash.  Definitely a helpful tool to learn.